# Facebook share link error

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook app and tried it to send invite a friend or share something on my wall, but I'm getting an error.

The same link is working with another app:

my app id:313714785358239

my link: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=313714785358239&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

and another link(working):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=123050457758183&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response

my error:
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you correctly configure domain and site URL (callback URL) to match the redirect_uri you're specifying as a parameter at the app request dialog.

You can configure these settings on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/313714785358239/summary

The App ID 123050457758183 has http://www.example.com as the callback URL and that's why it works.